# What is the best strategy for serial communication using WinAPI without knowing buffer size beforehand

Tags: c++, winapi, arduino, serial-port

Im trying to understand how serial communication works through windows API. Im using an Wemos board to send the message and reading in a C++ program. Both of these functions im using work. The HANDLE is a class variable. This is non overlapped and its a "listener":

```
void Serial::ReadSerialPort(int length)
{

   char* message = new char[length];

   DWORD nBytesRead;
   DWORD dwEvtMask;
   DWORD errors;
   BOOL bResult;
   COMSTAT status;

   ClearCommError(hCOM, &errors, &status);

   SetCommMask(hCOM, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR); //receive character event

   while (WaitCommEvent(hCOM, &dwEvtMask, 0)) { //wait for character

       if (dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR)
           bResult = ReadFile(hCOM, message, length, &nBytesRead, 0);


       else if (dwEvtMask & EV_ERR)
           std::cout << "error: " << dwEvtMask << std::endl;

       if (bResult && nBytesRead == 0)
       {
           std::cout << "end of file\n"; // this never happens anyway
       }

       //printing
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
           std::cout << message[i];
   }

}
```

This is overlapped:

```
LPCSTR Serial::ReadSerialPortOverlapped(int length) {
   OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 };
   BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
   BOOL bResult;
   char* message = new char[length];

   DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
   DWORD dwError;

   SetCommMask(hCOM, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR); //receive character event

   // Create the overlapped event. Must be closed before exiting
   // to avoid a handle leak.
   osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

   // Error creating overlapped event; abort.
   if (osReader.hEvent == NULL) {
       std::cout << "error";
   }

   if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
       // Issue read operation.
       bResult = ReadFile(hCOM, message, length, &dwBytesTransferred, &osReader);
       if (!bResult) {
           if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
               std::cout << "error\n" << std::endl;
           else {
               fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;

               while (fWaitingOnRead)
               {
                   fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
                
                   //pending

                   bResult = GetOverlappedResult(hCOM,
                       &osReader,
                       &dwBytesTransferred,
                       FALSE);

                   if (!bResult)
                   {
                       switch (dwError = GetLastError())
                       {
                          case ERROR_HANDLE_EOF:
                          {
                              // Handle an end of file
                              printf("GetOverlappedResult found EOF\n");
                              break;
                          }

                          case ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE:
                          {
                              // still incomplete
                              fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
                              break;
                          }
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       // completed
                       // Manual-reset event should be reset since it is now signaled.
                       ResetEvent(osReader.hEvent);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       else {
           // read completed immediately
       }

       return message;
    }
}
```

What i dont understand is that both of them will only work if i know beforehand the length of the message. If i provide a bigger buffer, let say for example, my message is "test", and my buffer is 10 in size, it will read the message but will keep waiting for more. But what if there isnt more, and i dont know the length beforehand? If i set a smaller buffer, for example, 1, and the message is bigger, it will only read the first character and skip the rest. This is a little weird to me because i was used to the recv() function where you can use a bigger buffer and it will stop reading when it finds that the stream is over. In arduino, Serial.read() with Serial.available() seems to be able to recognize the end of the stream.

Im accepting any tip on good ways to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the [`SetCommTimeouts()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommtimeouts) with a read timeout set to  just the right amount? Or will that not work for your case?

Comment: `Serial.available()` is simply when the ring buffer head is not equal to the ring buffer tail. See [the source code](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L166-L169)

Comment: Adrian I was hoping i could achieve that without using timeout, but i will try it, thanks.
@hcheung thats interesting, but is there a way to implement it on windows?

Comment: I just found out that there is a cbInQue variable from the COMSTAT structure that tells the number of bytes received not yet read by ReadFile(). I'll try to use it.